# how to change css for flip animation on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have managed to adapt a solution to get a password form to flip round into a sign in form using just css.
however, at the moment it just works on hover and not on click which is obviously what a user needs to be able to do otherwise one side of the form will never be able to filled out on hover.

here is a jsfiddle showing what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/xw6okx4n/

i thought about putting it into a js function and then calling the onclick method however my mind is just drawing blanks when i try to consider how you would call some of the particular css animation. 
alternatively is there a way with css that where i have hover below:

```
.flip3D:hover > .container2{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .container1{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

i can change it to 'click', 'button' or something else for example?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw6okx4n/1/). I removed the hover effect and replaced it with a call to a function, which toggles class `rotated` on `.flip3D` every time the button `#rotateButton` is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rotateButton").click(function() {
        $(".flip3D").toggleClass("rotated");
    });
});
```

So I had to change the hover CSS to:

```
.flip3D.rotated > .container2{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D.rotated > .container1{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

I believe it does exactly what you want it to do.